# See a black frame instead of a depth image with ASUS Xtion Pro and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, openni, asus-xtion

I can actually get a RGB image from my ASUS Xtion but cannot get any Depth image. I see a black image instead and no error shows up.

The sample SimpleView given with OpenNI works, so I guess it's not the sensor, not the library and OpenCV seems to work correctly.

Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    cout << "Device opening ..." << endl;
    VideoCapture captureStream;
    captureStream.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS);


    if( !captureStream.isOpened() ){
        cout << "Can not open capture object." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;){
        Mat depth;

        if( !captureStream.grab() ){
            cout << "ASUS Xtion can not grab images." << endl;
            return -1;
        }else
            if( captureStream.retrieve( depth, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP) )
                imshow("depth",depth);

        if( waitKey( 30 ) == 27 )   break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the depth-buffer actually all zeroes or just very low numbers so it seems like it's black?

Comment: How can I check the depth-buffer? (sorry, for the dumb question)

Comment: Ah sorry I meant just check the contents of the _depth_ Mat at certain points to see what kind of values it contains. The reason for this: The depth-map might be correct, but you might have to scale it to be visible.

Comment: Mmmmmh, now I've the following error: OpenNI_OpenCV_TrackingColorObject(4077,0x7fff7658e310) malloc: *** error for object 0x106c08000: pointer being freed was not allocated.

Comment: Oooh and I've got the following: [43, 4, 43]
[4, 43, 4]
[43, 4, 46]
[4, 46, 4]
[46, 4, 49]
[4, 46, 4]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]

Comment: Shouldn't the depth only have one channel (CV_16UC1)? This looks like color data. Please see also my answer below with sample code that you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenCV sample code](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/raw/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp) actually uses this code to retrieve and display the depth-map:

```
Mat depth;
capture.retrieve( depth, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP )
const float scaleFactor = 0.05f;
Mat show; 
depth.convertTo( show, CV_8UC1, scaleFactor );
imshow( "depth map", show );
```